# How do I prevent a Jquery countdown clock from moving as the time goes down?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm running into an issue using a countdown clock called loopcounter.js. It is center aligned. However, as the time goes down, the text moves slightly.

I've tried setting a max width for the p tag & setting margin: 0 auto, however I ran into the same issue.

```js
    $(function(){
        loopcounter('myCountdown');
    });
```

```css
body {
  background:#000000
}
.messaging {
  font-family:'Montserrat',sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-weight:600;
  font-size:20px;
  line-height:25px;
}

.myCountdown {
  background:green;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>



    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="messaging">Album Drops in  <span class="countdown-wrap"><span class="myCountdown" data-date="2023-11-26 23:59:59">
                            <span class="counter-hours"></span> : <span class="counter-minutes"></span> : <span class="counter-seconds"></span>
                        </span></span></p>

    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-w8CvhFs7iHNVUtnSP0YKEg00p9Ih13rlL9zGqvLdePA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/countdown-date-loop-counter/js/loopcounter.js"></script>  
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question writeup is not bad. It could be improved by posing a clear question at the bottom of the post. Can you [edit]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to set a fixed width for `.myCountdown` by making it a `inline-block` and using a `min-width` instead of `max-width`. Later if you want to also fix the texts inside **counter-hours** , **counter-minutes** and **counter-seconds**, you can  also make them `inline-block` with the same solution:

```js
    $(function(){
        loopcounter('myCountdown');
    });
```

```css
body {
  background:#000000
}
.messaging {
  font-family:'Montserrat',sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-weight:600;
  font-size:20px;
  line-height:25px;
}

.myCountdown {
  display:inline-block;
  min-width:180px;
  background:green;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>



    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="messaging">Album Drops in  <span class="countdown-wrap"><span class="myCountdown" data-date="2023-11-26 23:59:59">
                            <span class="counter-hours"></span> : <span class="counter-minutes"></span> : <span class="counter-seconds"></span>
                        </span></span></p>

    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-w8CvhFs7iHNVUtnSP0YKEg00p9Ih13rlL9zGqvLdePA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/countdown-date-loop-counter/js/loopcounter.js"></script>  
  </body>
 </html>
```